# What is the matrix that takes $\vec u$ to $\vec v$, where $\vec v$ is the derivative of u?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

The problem reads:

> $\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$, applying the differential operator to a function
>
> If we use the monomial basis $\vec e_n = x^n$ then a function $$\vec u(x) = \sum _i u_i\vec e_i$$ is identified with the column vector with components $u_i$. The derivative of this function is again a function, $$\frac{d}{dx}u(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_iu_i\vec e_i = \sum iu_i \vec e_{i-1}$$ This new vector can be expressed as $$\sum_iv_i \vec e_i$$ The differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ takes the fucntion u to the function v. What is the matrix that takes the vector $\vec u$ to $\vec v$?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What 's a basis for the space?  How does the differential operator act on the basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So

$$
\vec{v}(x)=\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}x}\vec{u}(x)
$$

$$
\sum_{j\geq 0}v_j\hat{e}_j=\sum_{j\geq 0}ju_j\hat{e}_{j-1}
$$

$$
v_{j-1}=ju_j
$$

$$
\vec{v}=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_0 \\
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
2 u_2 \\
3 u_3 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && \dots \\
0 && 0 && 2 && 0 && 0 && \dots \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 3 && 0 && \dots \\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_0 \\
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3 \\
\vdots \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
D=\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && \dots \\
0 && 0 && 2 && 0 && 0 && \dots \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 3 && 0 && \dots \\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In component form $D_{m,k}=k$ if $m=k-1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: is there a reason the first column is 0?

Comment: What's the derivative of a constant?

Comment: Oh i see okay thank you